# Search for Value then look in Google Sheet and display row values in html using google apps script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have a google spreadsheet that has menu for displaying a userform in html. The userform is a data entry form which enables you to add your input data to google spreadsheet. I added a button which should search an ID number in the Google Spreadsheet. Here is my html code for button and ID number:

html:

```
<div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">  
        <label for="idNum">ID Number</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idNum">
      </div>

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" id="searchbtn">Search Profile</button>

</div>
```

and here is my script for button search:

```
<script>
    //document.getElementById("addbtn").addEventListener("click", buttonAdd);
    document.getElementById("searchbtn").addEventListener("click", searchProfile);


   function searchProfile{

     var appProfile = document.getElementById("idNum").value;

     if(appProfile.length === 6){
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateProfile).updateIdNum(appProfile);
     } 
     //else{
     //alert("invalid Profile Number");
     }   
   }

   function updateProfile(returnData){
      document.getElementById("rnum").value = returnData[1];
   console.log(retData);

   }

    </script>
```

I was able to search the ID number but the problem is I don't know how to reflect or populate the fields in html using the values in the rows of the spreadsheet.

Here is my .gs code:

```
function updateProfNum(appProfile){
  //var appProfile = "101018"

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Results");

  var data = ws.getRange(1, 1, ws.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  var dJoin = data.join().split(",");
  vare myPnum = dJoin.indexOf(appProfile);
  var dataRow = ws.getRange(myPnum + 1, 1, 1, ws.getLastColumn()).getValues();


  if (myPnum > -1){
    return dataRow[0];
  } else {
    Logger.log("unknown")
    //return "unavailable";
  }

}
```

By the way, here is the sample of my spreadsheet data:

```
ID Number | First Name | Last Name|
101018    | John       | Doe      |
101011    | Jane       | Doe      |
```

I'm trying to reflect this data in my html userform by searching for the ID number using the button and then by getting the values in its row. (For example I'm searching for 101018 and when I click the button search, it will reflect the data in the userform. I hope anyone can help. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is mostly correct, it is just:

1. You are  missing the element with the Id `"rnum"` to which you want to assign the output.
   You can define e.g. `<output id="rnum"></output>`
2. You miss brackets `()` at `function searchProfile` and have some conflicts with function names.

Working code
Code.gs:

```
function updateIdNum(appProfile){
  //  var appProfile = "101018"

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Results");

  var data = ws.getRange(1, 1, ws.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  var dJoin = data.join().split(",");
  var myPnum = dJoin.indexOf(appProfile);
  var dataRow = ws.getRange(myPnum + 1, 1, 1, ws.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  Logger.log(dataRow[0]);

  if (myPnum > -1){
    return dataRow[0];
  } else {
    Logger.log("unknown")
    //return "unavailable";
  } 
}


function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
  .createMenu('Custom Menu')
  .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
  .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
  .setTitle('My custom sidebar')
  .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
  .showSidebar(html);
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">  
        <label for="idNum">ID Number</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idNum">
        <output id="rnum"></output>
      </div>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" id="searchbtn">Search Profile</button>
   </div>
<script>
    document.getElementById("searchbtn").addEventListener("click", searchProfile);
   function searchProfile(){
     var appProfile = document.getElementById("idNum").value;
     if(appProfile.length === 6){
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateProfile).updateIdNum(appProfile);
     } 
     //else{
     //alert("invalid Profile Number");
     }   
   function updateProfile(returnData){
      document.getElementById("rnum").value = returnData[1];
   }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my miss. I fixed it and now I'm receiving this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null". I'm trying to find a solution. Thank you so much

Comment: I think its the return from the google script. Logging the return google script it returned the values I need, But in the javascript, when I console.log the returned data (console.log(retData) "null" appeared. At first it was the cannot read property '1' of null but now its only "null"

Comment: Just realized that I pasted the wrong code for index.html, have a look now.